# SQL Server: how to change login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have many users in one database. All these users are named using "domain\" as a prefix. I would like to rename these user names by dropping this domain name from the user name. How to do that? In SQL Server Management Studio GUI user name is grayed and cannot be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not. The DOMAIN\user user is a user that has no password and is tied to a DOMAIN ACCOUNT. If you drop the DOMAIN\ refix, you ahve to assign it a password, basically moving authentication into the database.

User names can not be chanegd in SQL - you have to drop and recreate the login, then recreate the users in the databases.